# Dotenv not loading environment variables (Ubuntu, Yarn, Mocha)

Tags: javascript, node.js, yarnpkg

#### The issue

I'm working on an application that uses the `dotenv` package.

It's not currently setting any of the environment variables when I run `yarn test` or `yarn start` I'm getting errors because the environment variables are not being set.

`App.js` has this line near the top of the file
`require('dotenv').config();` - there are no references to `process.env` before this line of code is called.

#### Things i've tried

- Install `dotenv` globally.
- Completely delete the `node_modules` folder and rerun `yarn install`
- Providing the environment variables manually (this actually worked, but I've confirmed with another developer that the tests and the app is running just fine on his system without having to provide the environment variables manually.

#### `App.js` (entry point)

```
 7 require('dotenv').config();
```

#### `.env` (entry point)

```
LOG_LEVEL=testlevel
APP_NAME=testapp
```

#### `TestController.js` (consumer)

```
const log = logger(process.env.LOG_LEVEL, process.env.APP_NAME, 'TestController');
```

I'll take any help I can get at this point.

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? the `.env`file needs to be in the right location.

Comment: My ```.env``` file is in the root folder of the project

Comment: Can you post some code where you're initializing the dotenv, and then where you're trying to access a property?  Also, a snippet of what your dotenv file looks like would be good too (omit passwords n' stuff....)

Comment: Added some single liners that should get the point across

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out. Apparently the server was actually being started by mocha and there was a reference in there to `process.env` that was the problem. After adding the `require('dotenv').config()` to the beginning of the server file, the problem was resolved.

Thanks guys!